# How to pass all values from properties file as key to hashmap

Tags: java, properties, hashmap

I have a proprieties file which consist of few extries

```
a = true
b = yes
c = X
d = Y
e = true
r = yes
```

I would like to read this file and pass all the keys as key to hashmap and depending on which keys are present in hashmap, need to update the value

```
for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
    String value = properties.getProperty(key);
    mymap.put(key, Integer.valueOf(value));
}
```

It is not taking all the entries from properties file..
Can any one provide any other approach

Comment: try reading the javadocs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#propertyNames()

Comment: For the method you are using *Properties whose key or value is not of type String are omitted.*

Comment: none of the values above is an integer, how does your code work?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem here to solve. `Properties` is *already*  a hash map.

If you must get it into another `Map`, just use [`Map.putAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll-java.util.Map-).

Answer (score 0):

Use .entrySet() and iterate over .properties entries.

```
for (final Entry<Object, Object> entry :   properties.entrySet()) { 
map.put((String) entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue()); }
```